# Searching for value and then unwrapping those selected cells in a column

Tags: excel, find, vba

So I've been working on this for hours, and I feel like the solution is quite simple, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am receiving the error `Object Variable or With block variable not set`

```
Sub unwrap()
    Dim rgFound As Range
    Set rgFound = Range("A1:A500").Find("04/05/2017", LookIn:=xlValues)   
    If rgFound Is Nothing Then
        rgFound.WrapText = True
    Else
        rgFound.WrapText = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The cell where I am looking for `04/05/2017` also contains other dialogue so I'm not sure if that is the reason why my code isn't working.

The value `rgFound` is equal to `Nothing` as well and that doesn't make sense because there are cells in the column that clearly contain `04/05/2017`

Comment: You cant set `WrapText` if `rgFound` Is Nothing

Comment: Change the line `If rgFound Is Nothing Then` to `If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @braX: You might want to put that as an answer

Comment: Quick question, does the cell have only `04/05/2017` or it has other text as well?

Comment: It has other text as well @SiddharthRout . Ex: "04/05/2017    completed"

Comment: I thought so. I posted an answer. You may have to refresh th epage to see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The cell where I am looking for 04/05/2017 also contains other dialogue so I'm not sure if that is the reason why my code isn't working.
>
> It has other text as well @SiddharthRout . Ex: "04/05/2017 completed" – Peter Droz 2 mins ago

Using `.Find` is very dicey. Very few people know that `.Find` remembers it's last setting. And hence you should always specify what you want `.Find` to achieve. You need to use `LookAt:=xlPart`.

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    '~~> Change this as applicable
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    strSearch = "04/05/2017"
    
    Set aCell = oSht.Range("A1:A500").Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "found at " & aCell.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

You may also want to see [.Find and .FindNext In Excel VBA](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: I'm not sure why the code isn't functioning properly, but the column's cells still do not unwrap. So I'm not sure if the code is missing something else

Comment: We will come to unwrapping a bit later. First check if you were able to find the value

Comment: Perfect. Now replace `MsgBox "found at " & aCell.Address` with `aCell.WrapText = False`

Comment: So before I change the code, the MsgBox only found the value at A14, so when I ran the macro, it unwrapped the cell at A14 but that's it. How do we automate this so it covers the entire range from A1:A500.

Comment: For that you need to see `.FindNext` (Section 3) in the link at the bottom of my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer MATCH when looking through one column or row.

With Match we still need to deal with it not finding a match:

```
Sub unwrap()

Dim i as long

On Error Resume Next
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("*04/05/2017*",Range("A1:A500"),0)
On Error Goto 0

If i <> 0 then
    Range("A1:A500")(i).WrapText = True
Else
    Range("A1:A500").WrapText = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like I am still receiving an application-defined or object-defined error, and the debugger is highlighting the portion where   Range("A1:A500")(i).WrapText = False  .      If the cell said "04/05/2017  (done)" would it not match since the cell also contains more to the string?

Comment: The code works for me without error.  it successfully wraps the text in the correct cell when that cell data is `04/05/2017 (DONE)`  Did you leave in the `*` at the beginning and end of the date?

Comment: Sorry, when it is not found the I = 0 and you cannot have 0 as a reference, so I made the whole range change to no wrapped text.

Comment: Sorry to bother again Scott, I'm still getting object-defined error. It keeps having errors at the same spot as well, and I double checked the code to make sure it worked

Comment: Make sure you are using the most current, I edited the code.

Comment: Does Match work if there are other items written in the cell as well as the 04/05/2017?

Comment: Yes as long as you have the wildcards `*` at the beginning and end of the string `"*04/05/2017*"`

Comment: Your code functions (yay), except my cells didn't actually unwrap like they should have done. Instead everything is still the same. Let me know what may be the issue now

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
Set rgFound = Range("A1:A500").Find("4/5/2017", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Plus range.find returns nothing when it doesnt find the value. In that case you cannot wraptext on nothing. Maybe you should write this instead

```
Range("A1:A500").WrapText = True
```

Edit: If cells are wrapped by default then simply write

```
If Not (rgFound Is Nothing) Then
    rgFound.WrapText = False
End If
```

Comment: I'm only trying to have certain cells unwrapped, and the rest stay wrapped. All the cells I'm trying to wrap are already wrapped. But I'm trying to unwrap the cells in the column that contain  "4/5/2017".

Comment: @pnuts So of the 500 rows, about 1/3 of them contain the value 04/05/2017. I meant to say 04/05/2017 my apologies. If the cell matches with "04/05/2017" then I want to essentially uncheck the "wrap text" and unwrap the cell to get rid of blank space